# What is the daily storage limit for Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I've found some old resources on that:

1. [Why is (other) Showing Up in My Reports?](http://www.analyticsmarket.com/blog/other-reports-in-google-analytics)
2. [Google Analytics daily URL limit: does it affect URL-sequence goal tracking?](https://www.quora.com/Google-Analytics-daily-URL-limit-does-it-affect-URL-sequence-goal-tracking)
3. [Merging Google Analytics with your Data Warehouse](http://cutroni.com/blog/2011/05/05/merging-google-analytics-with-your-data-warehouse/)

I haven't been able to find any official documentation.
Is this limit still actual?

Especially for gtag.js

Comment: _Where I can find actual info on the subject?_ Ehh... read GA docs?

Comment: I tried to find some reasonable info on my issue there, but with no luck

Answer (score 0):

The daily limit that i have heard of is around 2 hits per day anything more than that and Google starts to drop hits.   The official limits can be found in the documentation below.

Directly from the documentation [Limits and quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/limits-quotas)

> These limits apply to the Web Property / Property / Tracking ID.
>
> 10 million hits per month per property
>   If you go over this limit, the Google Analytics team might contact you and ask you upgrade to Analytics 360 or implement client sampling to reduce the amount of data being sent to Google Analytics.
>
> For monthly total Analytics 360 limits, please contact your account manager or service representative.

The gtag.js appears to be the same [doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/limits-quotas)

Comment: Yes, I've studied limits and quotas already, but there is no any mention about daily limits for table rows

Comment: ok please define a table row.  this is a multi dimensional database here its not your concern how the data is stored